# Array item of type string does not work the same as string literal of the same value?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array `$pieces[]` that is an exploded URL, on which I perform some unsetting to drill it down to one value in the zeroth place. I store the value of `$pieces[0]` in `$category`. Let's say this value is the string `"page"`.

I pass `$category` to another array that contains various arguments for a function. In this array, if I pass `"page"` as a string literal, it performs as expected. If I pass `$category`, which *should* contain `"page"`, then it does not perform as expected. I have already casted the element from the first array as a string, and checking the type confirms that `$category` is a string.

Here is where the array creation and casting happens:

```
$current = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
$pieces = explode("/", $current);

foreach ($pieces as $key=>$piece) {
    if ($piece == "some value" || is_numeric($piece) || $piece == "") {
        unset($pieces[$key]);
    }
}

$category = $pieces[0]; //this is "page"
echo gettype($category); //returns NULL
$category = (string)$category;
echo gettype($category); //returns string
```

Then I try to use the variable in an array to no avail:

```
$newQuery = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type'        => 'post',
  'posts_per_page'   => 3,
  'category_name'    => $category,
  'paged'            => $paged,
));
```

What can I do?

Comment: When your code says `$category = $pieces[0]; //this is "page"`, _prove it_ by printing out its type and content. In fact, do a print_r for that `$pieces` array because you need to prove to yourself that there's even still anything in it. Turn this into an [mcve] by replacing that first line with `$current = "the actual string, so you can run this as standalone script";` and then running this code in isolation.

Comment: I also think you should take a closer look at your array. Request_uri normally starts with a slash. After explode $pieces[0] will be an empty string that you unset in your foreach. When you try to access it again you should get a E_NOTICE (depends on your error reporting), and $category should be NULL. This is consistent with the output of gettype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what happens :
In your foreach loop you unset empty pieces[]... If pieces[0] is unset, then after your foreach loop $pieces[0] no more exists and your final $pieces array finish like pieces[2=>"foo", 5=>"bar"];
You should not unset values of your array but create a new one with good values inside :

```
$new_array = [];
foreach ($pieces as $piece) {
    if ($piece != "some value" && !is_numeric($piece) && trim($piece) != "") {
        $new_array[] = $piece;
    }
}
$category = $new_array[0];
echo gettype($category); // I bet it works
```

Comment: You could alternatively use `array_values()`, but good point about element 0 being potentially not there.

Comment: Good call, upon further investigation the value I wanted was indeed in a different index.